# Set meta/command/⌘ key as Launchpad shortcut?

Tags: shortcut, launchpad

I would like to set the command key `⌘` as the shortcut to open Launchpad, is that possible? I've tried in the System Preferences, but it won't let me.

Comment: You cannot assign just the command key to Launchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you have to use a third party tool: Karabiner.

In the customized keycode below I assume that you haven't enabled the consumer key function in System Preferences but have to access the consumer keys by using the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F12</kbd>.

In the example below just the left command key launches Launchpad if hit once. A second hit will close Launchpad again.

You can use either the left or the right command key as usual otherwise (e.g. open files with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or print <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
           <name>When you type Command_L only, start Launchpad</name>
           <appendix>(Change Command_L lazy start Launchpad)</appendix>
           <identifier>remap.command_l_lazy_to_launchpad</identifier>
           <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::VK_LAZY_COMMAND_L, KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD, ModifierFlag::FN</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

Comment: Thank mate! This worked a treat! I'm a long time GNOME 3 user, and have got used to opening apps by pressing command, then searching and hitting enter. :)

Comment: @ChristopherBayliss it may have been useful to know that `⌘+space` brings up spotlight which allows you to search for and launch applications. Having also used GMOME3 extensively in the past, I usually hit both keys with one finger when using OS X to save adding extra configuration.